# php password, compare, return true or false

Tags: php, passwords

I have a file on my server called "pform.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<form action="password.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="password13"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

I have it transfer to another file called "password.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<?php

$text=$_GET["password13"];
$right="You entered the right password!";
$wrong="You entered the wrong password!";

if($password13)=="test"
{
    echo $right;
}
else
{
    echo $wrong;
}
?>
```

What can I change on line 7 that makes it compare the password "test" and  return true or false?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: @Polynomial Nope, I just do it for fun. I just started two days ago so I'm still new.

Comment: Please be aware that in a live application you should not roll your own password system, especially if it's your first time, there are far too many security issues that will come already solved in a third-party library.

Comment: That's not even correct syntax. Line 7 reports an unexpected T_IS_EQUAL if run.

Comment: For the record, a password should NEVER be passed in a GET variable as it's visible to everyone.

Comment: I know! It's just an example, I was going to change it to $_POST as soon as I could!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if($password13)=="test"
```

**should be**

```
if($text=="test")
```

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple:

```
$trueOrFalse = ($password13=="test");
if ($trueOrFalse) {
   ...
```

Or put it into the if clause directly:

```
if ("test" === $password13)
{
    ...
```

Comment: He's assigning the $_GET to $test, this will not work according to his example.

Comment: @Pastor Bones: He assigns it to `$text` not `$test`. So it looks like that register globals is on.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($text == "test")
```

not

```
if ($text) == "test"
```