# PHP password problems

Tags: php, passwords

I have a file on my server called "pform.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<form action="password.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="password13"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

I have it transfer to another file called "password.php", this is what it looks like:

```
<?php

$text=$_GET["password13"];
$right="You entered the right password!";
$wrong="You entered the wrong password!";

if($password13=="test")
{
    echo $right;
}
else
{
    echo $wrong;
}
?>
```

When I enter the right password, it returns false.

What can I change it so it returns true when I insert the right password?

Comment: `if($password13=="test")` ==> `if($text=="test")`

Comment: You never declare `$password13`, you need to use `$text`, as that's set to `$_GET["password13"]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php password, compare, return true or false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344827/php-password-compare-return-true-or-false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access it via `$text`, since that is the variable you have defined:

```
$text=$_GET["password13"];

// use $text, not $password13
if($text=="test")
{
    echo $right;
}
else
{
    echo $wrong;
}
```

Comment: As noted below, don't use _GET for sensitive information like passwords, I would suggest taking a look at @Jakub's post as this is bad practice as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($text == "test") 
   echo $right;
else
   echo $wrong;
```

Change your code to this. Your $password13 variable is not defined

Answer (score 1):

check for $test, as $password13 does not exist :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would change your form so that it submit at least as `POST`, and mask the password by making the input 'password'

```
<form action="password.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="password13"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

Then reference the variable like so:

```
<?php

$text=$_POST["password13"];
$right="You entered the right password!";
$wrong="You entered the wrong password!";
...
```

remember to reference `$text` when you compare your password value.

Answer (score 1):

Never use $_GET parameters for sensitive data like passwords and such, they are stored inside browser cache, server logs, and are a huge security risk.

Use $_POST like Jakub has written for you above.